# Convert SQL to LINQ Troubles

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I have been stuck on this for an embarrassing day... can't seem to convert this to linq.  My issue also is that Attendee can be null.

```
select c.activityId, count(distinct b.attendeeId)
from Attendee a, sponsor_activity c
left outer join sponsor_attendance b
on c.ActivityId = b.ActivityId
where  a.RegistrationId = 62
AND c.SponsorLevelId = 2
group by c.activityId
```

So far I have this code... but I am not getting distinct values

```
var activity_count = (from c in db.Sponsor_Activitys
where c.SponsorLevelId == pledgelvl
from a in db.Attendees.DefaultIfEmpty()
where a.RegistrationId == registration
select new { Activityid = c.ActivityId, NumAttending = db.Sponsor_Attendances.Count(x => x.ActivityId == c.ActivityId) })
.ToList();
```

### **Sponsor_Attendance**

```
AttendanceId
AttendeeId
ActivityId
```

### **Sponsor_Activity**

```
ActivityId
SponsorLevelId
```

### **Attendee**

```
AttendeeId
RegistrationId
```

Returns:

```
## ActivityID ##  ## NumAttending ##
2                   4
3                   0
4                   2
2                   4
3                   0
4                   2
2                   4
3                   0
4                   2
```

Currently there are 3 attendees that have a registrationid that matches... so this is why it is repeated 3 times in the output.

Comment: What have you tried so far?  You should be looking for left join linq syntax.  There should be a large number of examples on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Just updated my question with what I have going on right now

Comment: It would be easier if you post the table structure and output.

Comment: Updated with table structure and output... sorry for not having all that is needed to help :)

Comment: You're mixing join types - `from Attendee a, sponsor_activity c
left outer join sponsor_attendance b`. You should always use the regular `join` syntax. That would be a helpful starting point. Also, you don't always need to use LINQ - quite often it's better for readability, development time, and performance, to just stick with a stored proc.

Answer (score 0):

First, it helps if your original queries are readable. :)

Query:

```
SELECT  c.activityId
      , COUNT(DISTINCT b.attendeeId)
FROM    Attendee a
      , sponsor_activity c
LEFT OUTER JOIN sponsor_attendance b
        ON c.ActivityId = b.ActivityId
WHERE   a.RegistrationId = 62 AND
        c.SponsorLevelId = 2
GROUP BY c.activityId;
```

Linq:

```
var activity_count = (from activity in db.Sponsor_Activitys
                      where activity.SponsorLevelId == pledgelvl
                      from attendee in db.Attendees.DefaultIfEmpty()
                      where attendee.RegistrationId == registration
                      select new
                      {
                          Activityid = activity.ActivityId,
                          NumAttending = db.Sponsor_Attendances.Count(x => x.ActivityId == activity.ActivityId)
                      }).ToList();
```

My answer:

```
   var query = from activity in db.Sponsor_Activitys

            // Left outer join onto sponsor_attendances
            join attendance in db.Sponsor_Attendances
            on activity.ActivityId equals attendance.ActivityId into g
            from q in g.DefaultIfEmpty()

            join attendee in db.Attendees
            on q.AttendeeId equals attendee.AttendeeId

            where attendee.RegistrationId == registration && 
                  activity.SponsorLevelId == pledgelvl

            select new
            {
                Activityid = activity.ActivityId,
                NumAttending = db.Sponsor_Attendances.Count(x => x.ActivityId == activity.ActivityId)
            }
```

Given the cartesian join (typically bad!), this might be a better example on just executing SQL rather than trying to convert to Linq.

Comment: Thanks Cameron, and next time I ask a question I will work on formatting.  :)

Comment: Well this works, but it looks like the join doesnt work as I expected.  I really need all of the the activityId's from Sponsor_Activity regardless if there is someone attending or not.  If no attendees then it should state 0.